# creating multiple DHCP pools in server 2008 and 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a DHCP server connected to 3 different devices having different VLANs through switch.
now i want to create 3 DHCP pools having Different networks on server. how can i configure it so they automatically provide IPs to the connected 3 devices?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to add a DHCP helper to each of the 3 VLANS in your switch.  Configure three IP Scopes on the server one for each subnet associated with each VLAN.